# Delete labeled levels under a variable in R

Tags: r, variables, levels

I have a variable called "Item" and it has levels that are labeled as ( 111, 112, 113, 114, etc). Each item is repeated 20 times one for each subject. The items are in rows and each are linked to the dependent variable (RT). I found that some items need to be deleted (high error rates). What codes should I write in R for it to delete or exclude, for example, items (111, 114, 222, and 319) from the the data frame so I can run the analysis without these items and their RT. 
I have tried running the following codes with mydata, but they did not work:

```
    Deleted <- droplevels(mydata[mydata$Item != "111, 114, 222, 319", ])
    summary(Deleted)
```

The summary of "deleted" show still show these items

I have also tried

```
Deleted <- names(mydata$Item) %in% c("111", "114", "214")
newdata <- qp[!Deleted]
summary(newdata)
```

I get the following after summary

```
Error in z[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In max(unlist(lapply(z, NROW))) :
 no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

and for levels()

```
levels(newdata$Item)
NULL
```

I feel that I am missing a something, but I cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `mydata` as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(item=rep(100:400,each=20), RT=sample(0:100,6020, replace=T))
```

Then the following all produce the same thing:

```
to.delete  <- mydata$item %in% c(111,114,222,319)             # two steps
scrubbed.1 <- mydata[!to.delete,]

scrubbed.2 <- mydata[!(mydata$item %in% c(111,114,222,319)),] # same, one step

# @MatthewLundberg's approach (he left out a comma before the right bracket...]
scrubbed.3 <- droplevels(mydata[!(mydata$item %in% c(111,114,222,319)),])

identical(scrubbed.1,scrubbed.2)
#  [1] TRUE
identical(scrubbed.1,scrubbed.3)
#  [1] TRUE
```

Your first approach failed because you were comparing `df$item` to a string "111, 114, 222, 319". None of the items match that string, hence no deletions.

Comment: I followed what you have suggested, but mydata ended up  excluding all the other independent variables (shows only items and RT). Also, the Item labeling are not in order. That is, each item are specified with a certain number that is link to a condition. For example, I have 5 conditions and each condition include 24 items, so condition one is labeled from 111 to 134, condition 2 (211-234) and so on. I think I should include all variables in the set.seed function and indicate the item labeling, but I am not sure how to correctly go about this.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first two lines of code above just create a sample dataset to illustrate the method. The data frame `mydata` in this example has *nothing whatsoever* to do with your version of `mydata`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want this:

```
Deleted <- droplevels(mydata[!(mydata$Item %in% c(111, 114, 222, 319) )])
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I got "Error in `[.data.frame`(mydata, !(mydata$Item %in% c(111, 114, 222, 319))) : 
  undefined columns selected" The items are labeled and repeated in rows as "111, 114, etc" What do you think the issue is?